# Access AS400/DB2 with SQL 2008 Express

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to add the AS400 as a linked server in SQL 2008 Express in order to access some tables in a DB on the iSeries. I've tried all of the OLE providers with many different strings and have had no luck establishing a connection. Is this even possible with this version of SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble with the AS/400 OLE DB Providers as well.  So I cheated and used ODBC instead.  Create a system DSN to connect to your AS/400.  Then create the linked server like this:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
   @server = 'MyServer', 
   @srvproduct = '',
   @provider = 'MSDASQL', 
   @datasrc = 'AS400'
```

In the prior example, I gave my system DSN the name of "AS400".  Within SQL Express, the server is called "MyServer".  Here's the problem with this solution:  I used the iSeries Access ODBC provider and, by default, I don't store my password on my local machine.  So I had to make sure I was connected to the AS/400 by bringing up a green-screen session first.

Anyway, once the linked server definition is added and you have an active connection, or a password issue worked out with your ODBC connection, you just run a query to get your data like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyServer.MySystem.MyLibrary.MyFile
```

Where "**MyServer**" is the name you put in the @server= part of the sp_addlinkedserver call.  "**MySystem**" is your AS/400 database name.  You can determine this value by logging on to green screen and using the WRKRDBDIRE command.  The entry with the remote location of *LOCAL is your database name.  "**MyLibrary**" and "**MyFile**" are self explanatory.

It feels like a kludgy solution, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I've same problem with you, but this solution works for me. 
After adding the linked server, somehow the library & table doesn't show..but it's connected.
Just try this query :

```
select * from OpenQUery(<name_of_linked_server>, 'select * from <library>.<table>');
```

You can check the detail
[here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas1d7cd7e4509cc894c86257280005c65dc)